# Pytorch: What is the best way to sample two items of different labels form a dataset?

Tags: python, pytorch, pytorch-lightning, pytorch-dataloader

I'm trying to define a pytorch `Dataset`/`Dataloader` for an image style transfer network. I have a dataset of images grouped by styles, and I want each sample from this dataset to consist of two images, one for style, the other for content. My first idea was to implement a `Dataset` with something like this in `__init__`:

```py
n = len(images)
itr_style = random.shuffle([i for i in range(n)]))
itr_content = random.shuffle([i for i in range(n)]))
```

and this in `__getitem__`:

```py
return (images[itr_style[index]], images[itr_content[index]])
```

Which is probably not the most efficient implementation, and I also need to make sure that:

1. The two images don't come from the same style
2. The dataset re-shuffles every epoch

So what is the best way to implement this `Dataset`?

Comment: You don't need to shuffle images in `__init__`. `Dataloader` has shuffle option, and calling `dataloader = Dataloader(dataset, shuffle=True)` in each epoch will shuffle your dataset.

Comment: @minolee Yes, I'm aware, but I'm not sure how to get two indices with `Dataloader`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understood you want to make combination of two images, which are from different groups.

Assuming you have group of images, you can preload every combination of image index from each group, and load image from `__getitem__`.

```
from typing import List
from torch.utils.data import Dataset

class Image():
    """Placeholder class - you may change Image class into some tensor objects"""
    pass

class PreloadedDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, img_groups: List[List[Image]]):
        super(PreloadedDataset, self).__init__()
        self.groups = img_groups
        self.combinations = []
        for group_idx1, group1 in enumerate(img_groups):
            for group_idx2, group2 in enumerate(img_groups[group_idx1:]):
                for img1 in range(len(group1)):
                    for img2 in range(len(group2)):
                        self.combinations.append((group_idx1, img1, group_idx2, img2))

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.combinations)

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        group1, img1, group2, img2 = self.combinations[item]
        return self.groups[group1][img1], self.groups[group2][img2]
```